# How to clear the response and set response status in post-filter?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to add a layer of access control in an api gateway that, when a certain condition is met, removes the content from the response and sets the status to 403.

This is where I have gotten so far:

```java
public class MyFilter extends GatewayFilter{
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain){
    //MyDecorator extends ServerHttpResponseDecorator
    MyDecorator decorator=new MyDecorator(exchange.getResponse);
    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(decorator).build()).then(Mono.fromRunnable(()->{
      //...
      if(certainCondition){
        clearResponseAndSetForbidden(decorator);
      }
    });
  }

  private void clearResponseAndSetForbidden(MyDecorator response){
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.forbidden);
    AbstractListenerServerHttpResponse listenerResponse=(AbstractListenerServerHttpResponse)response.getDelegate();
    HttpServletResponse nativeresponse=listenerResponse.getNativeResponse();
    nativeResponse.resetBuffer();
    nativeResponse.setContentLength(0);
    response.setComplete();
  }
}
```

I'm having a weird issue with this. If I invoke `response.setComplete()` in the end of `clearResponseAndSetForbidden`, the status code gets re-written to 200 but the response body remains empy. If I *don't* invoke it, the response status is 403 but the body gets written.

How do I get the gateway to do both?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to set the decorator in a filter with the order `-2`. The global filter that writes the response is ordered `-1`, so this ensures the write operation uses the decorated response.
Then, I added a flag to `MyDecorator` that is used to bypass the write operation:

```java
public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer) body){
  return super.writeWith(body.map( buffer->{
    if(isFailed){
      return bufferFactory.wrap(new byte[0]);
    }
    return buffer;
  });
}
```

Then, replace the manipulation of `nativeResponse` with just setting the flag in the decorator. The original filter can be left at the default order.